# IPFS file is still showing after deletion

Tags: ipfs

I understand in ipfs all peers caches parts of my uploaded file. Is it true even if i dont share my file with anyone(node)? I uploaded and immediately deleted a file but the file is still visible with the link.
Does all my connected ipfs peers cache files whenever i uploads a new file?

Answer (score 1):

If you added a file to IPFS, and you want it removed, you need:

1. No one other nodes to have the file pinned
2. File unpinned from your own node
3. File removed from your MFS (if it was added)
4. Garbage collected (`ipfs repo gc`)

When all the above is true, the file is gone.

Comment: When i upload a file, that file is fragmented into parts and those small parts are persisted in several nodes(local storage of those computer) right? Or the entire file is saved in my own computer?

Comment: Some files, along with their parts may be cached in other nodes temporarily, but if they don't have it pinned, it likely won't survive in their cache for very long. I believe nodes will typically store all the blocks a file requires, rather than just fragments.

Comment: Also to answer your save question. Yes, when you add a file to your IPFS node, it's only added locally.